# How to make a div, that's under a fixed div, reposition itself when the fixed div's height changes?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have the following page in my rails app

```
.col-md-10
  .row
    #dict
      #character
        %strong Character:
      #pronunciation
        %strong Pinyin:
      #meaning
        %strong Meaning:
  .row
    #text-part
  ...
```

I want the #dict to be fixed at the top of the site so I added the following css:

```
#dict {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

That fixed the div across the screen[image: Fixed div]

However, the content in that fixed div is dynamic (changes based on which word is clicked by the user). When a word with longer definition is selected, the fixed div covers the div under it, [image: like so]
How can I make the bottom div reposition in response to the fixed div? Also, the fixed div spans across the screen and beyond, so sometimes the content in it is not visible. How to position it correctly is only stretches within the .col-md-10 div?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out by using javascript to chang #text-part margin-top when getting a new dictionary entry OR resizing window:

```
DivResizer=
  reposition_text_entry: ->
    current_dictionary_height = $("#dict").css('height')
    $("#text-part").css('margin-top', current_dictionary_height)


  adjust_dict_width: ->
    text_part_width = $("#text-part").css('width')
    $("#dict").css("width", text_part_width)

ready = ->
  $( window ).resize ->
    DivResizer.reposition_text_entry()
    DivResizer.adjust_dict_width()
```

With #dict width I also used Javascript but there must be some easier way with just CSS.